# Dependency injection compared to global interfaces

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection, interface, global

One of the reasons I see for preferring dependency injection over global variables is that it becomes difficult to mock a global during testing. But suppose I declare the global as an interface, I can avoid this problem.

```
package restclient
type HTTPClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

var (
    Client HTTPClient
)

func init() {
    Client = &http.Client{}
}
```

In the above example, I am creating a global interface and initializing it to an http client. So whenever I want to make a REST call, I make use of this interface.
Now In my test cases, if I want to mock the http client, all I need to do is

```
restclient.Client = new(RestclientMock)
```

So wouldn't this approach of using global interfaces be much better than using dependency injection considering the simplicity?

Comment: The opening sentence sounds odd to me: a well-engeneered Go program does not contain global variables and does not make use of DI—instead, you use interfaces to specify behavioral contracts for key objects of which you'd like to have multiple swappable implementations, _including for testing,_ and then you have plain boring code which creates the objects of the necessary types and passes them down to the code which creates other objects etc—all the way down to  "leaf" objects. The latter is what DI fluff does under its cover.

Comment: That‘s totally wierd. Why would you mock a http.Client?

Comment: @Volker How would you test a piece of code that is calling an external API. If I do not mock it, it would make the actual http call itself right?

Comment: @kostix You told a well engineered Go program does not make use of DI. But isn't what you told to do instead DI itself `you have plain boring code which creates the objects of the necessary types and passes them down to the code which creates other objects`.  I am quite new to go and I would really appreciate it if you can share me some link which shows how to do it in the ideal way.

Comment: «How would you test a piece of code that is calling an external API.» Usually you do that with the help of [`httptest.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server).

Comment: Regarding to your response about DI, I failed to parse it, sorry. Were you trying to state that «plain boring code which creates the objects of the necessary types and passes them down to the code which creates other objects» is what one calls DI? If yes, then _technically_ that can be called DI but the problem is that these days when one mentions DI, in most cases the person means _using a framework_ which takes some form of _configuration_ (which is not Go code) and either turns it into a generated code (like, say, [wire](https://github.com/google/wire)) or does the same at runtime.

Comment: I'd speculate that the prevailing opinion common among seasoned Go devs is that one should start small and only begin to depend on advanced stuff _after_ a need for it was clearly identified—from particular difficulties with maintaining code, for instance,—and _after_ doing careful engeneering evaluations of all the pros and cons of starting depending on a new 3rd-party library/framework. I recommend you to start with [this funny video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi5A3cK1LNA) which is a good intro to not having premature depencies :-)

Comment: Thanks for the httptest.Server advice and the link. I will definitely check it out. And yes what you specified itself is what I meant by DI and thats how I have written my code currently. But that approach has resulted in the code having lots of large constructors and lot of boring code to inject each dependency.  So recently I saw a person using this new method of global interfaces. This new approach seemed quite easy to me and strange that it is not that popular. So thats why I posted this question to find out if there are any other drawbacks in using this new approach.

Comment: What‘s wrong with making an actual HTTP call during testing?

Comment: @Volker For example, the external API call could be to send a communication to a user. I wouldn't want the user to get a communication every time my unit test runs.

Comment: Of  course you do not call some external API which has unwanted side effects. Of  course you call a local stub or fake of the external API. The question was not "What‘s wrong with making an actual HTTP call to a not-side-efect-free 3rd party API during testing?" but "What‘s wrong with making an actual HTTP **call** during testing?" because that _call_ is what you can omit with your strange pattern. Sorry if I was unclear. Set up a local stub/fake as kostix explained how to do. Don't mock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this approach regarding testing starts to become clear when thinking of multiple tests running in parallel.

One test will set the global variable to be able to test with it and while testing, it gets overwritten by the next test, resulting in unpredictable behaviour for both tests. They now influence each other, using the same instance of the dependency.

Note: Actually, you can even experience the issue without enabling parallel execution of tests. Especially if the dependency has internal goroutines that could live beyond the execution of the test they were created for.

Comment: Thats a good point.